# C++ / C printf family

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

At the moment, there are tags for many members of the `printf`-family of library functions, though not for all ([printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf), [sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprintf), [fprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fprintf), [snprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snprintf), [vsprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsprintf), [vsnprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsnprintf), [vswprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vswprintf)).

I propose merging and synonymising them all to [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf), because:

1. Often at least one other member of the family is used in the question.
2. Sometimes only another member of the family is actually used in the question.
3. Even if both 1 and 2 do not apply, the answers are at least likely to recommend another member of the family.
4. Just about every explanation / use of one member of that family applies to them all with at most slight variation, so the exact one mentioned is quite arbitrary.
5. Another point which supports 4, they are all handled together or at least in as big a group as makes sense for the format in common documentation like the C / C++ / POSIX standards, `man` and `info`-pages. (thanks @anthony-arnold)
6. Merging alone is not enough, because someone would inadvertently recreate them for sure.

This post is mainly here to get those who can endorse my proposal to notice the pending synonyms.

[Direct link to the synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/printf/synonyms), where they can be upvoted or downvoted, depending on your approval or disapproval of my proposal, assuming you have sufficient answer score in the tag.

Comment: What about using a more generic tag, like "output" ?

Comment: @NickL.:"output" would be too generic: Besides it not implying formtting, especially using a formatting string, `printf` is already an institution copied to other languages. Anyway, there are many other domain-specific-languages for formatted output.

Comment: "formatted-print" could be another idea. The difference with "printf" tag is that printf is directly associated with C only, in a sense.

Comment: @NickL.: It might have originated there (AFAICT it did), but it was imported wholly into PHP and others, so is no longer restricted to C++ and C (not that that is important here). `formatted-print` does neither convey the specific DSL used, nor is it recognized as the appropriate tag for using format strings, nor is it a tag at all atm.

Comment: @NickL. Also, most Unixes now have a "printf" command, so it can be used in shell scripts, too.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it actually makes a difference to anyone, but I typically don't accept an answer until the request is completed (unless you figured it would be marked [tag:status-completed], although these don't get often marked as such).

Comment: Grouping all of these tags together would be in line with convention. Most man pages/documentation groups all of these functions together.

Comment: @Dukeling: Thanks, that's actually a good reason not to mark anything as accepted yet. I just haven't done that much on meta yet.

Comment: [varargs] would be the more generic tag.  But it is a meta-tag and adds very little.  Most any C or C++ user would know how to answer such a question.  So no point in changing them either.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Even if there might be a more general term that would include all the printf types, unless we clearly agree on one, I do still believe that merging all the printf variants into just [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf) is the right step.

[sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprintf), [fprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fprintf), [snprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snprintf), [vsprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsprintf), [vsnprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsnprintf), [vswprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vswprintf) are all the same `printf` function except that they have the output go somewhere else or accept a different kind of input. It’s like function overloading in other languages. So even if there are differences, they are somewhat minor as the main purpose of `printf` is to take some variable arguments and construct a formatted string from them according to a format string which all those function share.

So yes, I would support synonymizing those tags into [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf) for now. If we later find a more general term, then we can always change it again.

Answer (score 6):

I'm personally against a blind synonymization in this case.

Don't get me wrong - I'm not saying synonymization is a bad idea, I just don't think we should do so without looking at most / all questions with these tags.

If there's even a remote possibility of someone asking a question which is specific to one / some of the functions, but not the rest (which I definitely think there is), we shouldn't synonymize them without first trying to identify these or establish, with sufficient certainty, that such questions don't exist, or are rare enough that a tag dedicated to them is not particularly useful.

If can't identify sufficient questions to justify different tags (after looking through the questions), we could synonymize them.

If we do identify questions to justify different tags, we might keep [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf) as the master tag (based on my knowledge of C and C++, the chances of a question unique to `printf` seems particularly rare) or perhaps a [generic-printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generic-printf) or [printf-generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf-generic).

If some of the tags are justified, but not all, we should perhaps consider just merging the others into [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf) (not synonymizing them), allowing the creation of these tag were questions to pop up where the tag is justified.

Comment: I'm with you on this. Though they all share the `printf` base functionality, the `n` and `v` versions often have questions asked about those particular features of the functions.  Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823895/c-vsprintf-and-variable-arguments-list).  The fact that `va_start` and `va_end` are necessary to the `vsprintf` call is an imperative point of the answers -- and anyone searching for a `vsprintf` answer will necessarily need to know that.  I say, leave them separate, but let any of them imply `printf`.

Comment: @bishop: Actually, that is a bad question using bad tags trying to make something work despite abysmal decisions, which are not adressed. Imho. Correct me if I'm wrong about any of those particulars.

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree that that's a bad question, since it basically says "my code doesn't work", but doesn't show any code. Although I think the basic idea is there - a question specifically pertaining to `va_list` definitely isn't applicable to the entire `printf` family of functions - perhaps tagging such a question with [tag:va-list] instead would be more appropriate then, but, either way, that supports the point in my answer - we need to look at individual questions, not blindly synonymize them.

Comment: @Dukeling: Adding more appropriate tags is always a nice idea, but the `vsprintf`-tag does not add any value there over `printf` imnsho. Still, it's always debatable when a minor quirk becomes a major change.

Comment: I'm with you, there are a lot of times for my Systems Programming class where I had to search up specific variations of `printf` because we almost never use `printf`, instead we use `fprintf` (for debugging), sprintf, and etc.

To me, a closely-related example would be if we wanted to synchronize all the family of `exec`, which I think is a NO NO.