# Please burn [document.ready] and [document-ready]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Both tags have the same meaning, although [only one question is tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-ready+document.ready).

Please merge [document.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document.ready) into [document-ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-ready).

Comment: @KevinBrown [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7126727) [proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7126728)

Comment: Correct tag wiki is good to go!

Comment: Please don't.​​ What about this tag is useful to anyone whatsoever? Nuke it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Very true. Post updated.

Comment: There are currently 210 questions tagged `[document-ready]`. Although some of those could very well do without the tag, I just want to point out that `$(document).ready()` is a jQuery idiosyncrasy that is not always easy to get (and may bite you sometimes). Keeping a tag around this feature (possibly with a more focused name like `[jquery-ready]`) does not look like such a bad thing to me.

Comment: (As an aside, relying on upvoted comments to deduce the "popular opinion" is biased because comments cannot be downvoted.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I wanted to downvote your comment but I couldn't, so I settled for upvoting it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I can't think of a single example of a jQuery question I've seen where the issue was the usage of `$(document).ready()`, though. There are loads caused by the fact that people don't know it exists and therefore aren't using it when they need to, but they're not going to use a tag in that case.

Comment: @Anthony, if you sort [by votes, descending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-ready?sort=votes&pageSize=50), you will find a few interesting questions that are directly related to `ready()`. There are also some lower-profiles ones, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19833697/464709) or [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17741531/464709).

Comment: I have no opinion about this myself, but can I suggest the question should be "what to do with these tags". There should be two answers (1) Burninate (2) rename. Then it would be possible to use answer upvotes/downvotes to determine the most popular option.

Comment: Aside note; `document-ready` > "**Use this tag for questions about javascript functions that run after the page is loaded.**" ... pretty all encompassing, as stated... but it does bring in to question whether the appropriate tag would be in regards to 'lifecycles' (for a lack of a better word regarding loading and execution states in concept).

Comment: is `document.ready` synonymous with `javascript`? Is `DOM` synonymous with `javascript`? .. (rhetorical question)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: That may be the case, but the purpose of tags is not to cover every single aspect of a thing. If we have `jquery-ready`, why can't we also have `jquery-on`, `jquery-each`, `jquery-find`, `jquery-closest`, etc. Tags just don't need to be that granular.

Comment: `$(document).ready(...)` is a single method in jQuery. Does it really deserve or require its own tag?

Comment: @cpburnz, [printf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printf) is a single function in C. Yet its tag currently decorates 3974 questions.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `printf()` (and family) have a mini-language with its string formatting, but I don't know if it necessarily deserves a tag of its own. `$(document).ready()` takes exactly one argument: a function to call when the document is ready. I do not think that necessitates a tag; otherwise, you might as well have a bunch of tags for every commonly used jQuery method.

Comment: `printf` once had more than a handful tags, one for each C-function. Now it's only one tag for the whole family: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251192/c-c-printf-family

Comment: Option 4: merge them with `domcontentloaded`.

Answer (score 28):

Option 3: Merge all into [document-ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-ready).

Comment: Done, tags merged and  [tag:document.ready] -> [tag:document-ready] synonym setup